# How can I wrap edittext without using multiline?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/customedittext"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/timeandspace"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:hint="1."
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colormain"
                android:textSize="25sp" /></LinearLayout>
```

How can I wrap the text vertically or set a maximum width of my text without using `android:inputType="textmultiline"`?

reason if why i didnt want that input type because i am using the Enter in keyboard to submit the text and not to add line. Hope someone can help me :)

And, how can I prevent automatically showing keyboard and focus to edittext at the start of activity?

Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

**This will not add a line:**

> reason if why i didnt want that input type because i am using the
>   Enter in keyboard to submit the text and not to add line

```
answer1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        // Do whatever you wanna do on "Enter"

        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

> And, how can I prevent automatically showing keyboard and focus to
>   edittext at the start of activity?

Remove any `EditText.requestFocus()` call in your activity.